# Title Bar Text Gets Highlighted

Tags: windows-10

I don't know how or why this annoying problem started but every title bar of Apps which I am using gets highlighted, like this:

[image]

I am using Windows 10, non-anniversary!
How to remove this? Thanks.

Comment: do you use a 3rd party theme that adds the glow from 7 back?

Comment: @magicandre1981 no I don't!